# JFrame animated resize Mac OS X style

Tags: java, animation, resize, jframe

In Mac OS X, some windows change their size with gradual animation (growing/shrinking) when switching between different tabs (e.g. System Preferences window).
What would be the best way to achieve such effect using JFrame (Java) without visual flickering or performance hit.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

to shrink a little bit

```
new Thread(new Runnable()
{
   public void run()
   {
        Dimension dim = jframe.getSize();
        while (dim.getHeight() >= someheightintegeryouwanttoshrintto)
        {
            try
            {
                jframe.setSize((int)(dim.getWidth()), (int)(dim.getHeight()-1));
                Thread.sleep(1);
            }
            catch(InterruptedException ex) 
            {

            }
            dim = jframe.getSize();
        }
    }
}).start();
```

to grow a little bit

```
new Thread(new Runnable()
{
   public void run()
   {
        Dimension dim = jframe.getSize();
        while (dim.getHeight() <= sometheightyouwanttoincreaseto)
        {
            try
            {
                jframe.setSize((int)(dim.getWidth()), (int)(dim.getHeight()+1));
                Thread.sleep(1);
            }
            catch(InterruptedException ex) 
            {

            }
            dim = jframe.getSize();
        }
    }
}).start();
```

Comment: This is calling Swing methods from a background thread, so I'm not sure it can be recommended.

Answer (score 0):

I use a single JFrame and resize it after replacing the JPanels. It gives that Mac OS X style of animation (A little parameter changing might be required in the LauncherTask class though to make it animate more perfectly)

I put this line of code in the main JFrame class i.e. Launcher.java in my case. Configuration class extends JPanel class and I use this.setPreferredSize() to set it's size (This will be used in the LauncherTask class to resize accordingly)

```
(new Thread(new Configuration(this))).start();
```

This is a class file for resizing Jpanels

```
package com.imoz;

import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;

public class LauncherTask extends SwingWorker<Void, Void> {

float x,y,dx,dy,pixel;
private JFrame parent;
private Dimension target;

public LauncherTask(JFrame parent, Dimension target) {
    this.parent = parent;
    this.target = target;
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
    dx = (float) Math.abs(parent.getWidth() - target.getWidth());
    dy = (float) Math.abs(parent.getHeight() - target.getHeight());

    if( dx >= dy )
        pixel=dx;
    else
        pixel=dy;

    pixel /= 7.5;
    dx=dx/pixel;
    dy=dy/pixel;
    x=parent.getWidth();
    y=parent.getHeight();

    boolean dxGrow = true, dyGrow = true;
    if(parent.getWidth() < target.getWidth())
        dxGrow = false;
    if(parent.getHeight() < target.getHeight())
        dyGrow = false;

    float i = 1f;
    while(i <= pixel)
    {
        if(dxGrow)
            x -= dx;
        else
            x += dx;
        if(dyGrow)
            y -= dy;
        else
            y += dy;

        parent.setSize((int)x, (int)y);
        parent.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        parent.invalidate();

        i+=1;
    }
    parent.setSize((int)target.getWidth(), (int)target.getHeight());
    parent.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    return null;
}
```

}